# Possible to Create Unencrypted Folder Outside Ecryptfs Home?

Tags: ecryptfs

Dropbox is dropping support for ecryptfs directories. Is it possible to create a directory outside the encrypted home directory that a user can access, where the Dropbox folder can be moved to?

Comment: Supposedly yes but so many changes happened recently with Dropbox that I'm not sure what are their current requirements.

Comment: The above should be understood as "supposedly yes" to creating a folder in a non-encrypted **partition** somewhere else. Whether or not Dropbox can use it I don't know. Ask them.

Comment: Does the version of dropbox you installed have a man page or help text (`-h` or `--help` maybe) or documentation? If it's the GUI, it should have a setting under a Sync tab I think

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

Assuming you have sudo rights (and your `/home` partition is on an Ext4 filesystem) you can simply create a new folder outside of your home directory (e.g. `/home/dropbox`) and tell Dropbox to move itself to this folder.

Don't forget to set the appropriate permissions on the new folder so your account has access.

```
sudo mkdir -m 700 /home/dropbox
sudo chown yourname:yourgroup /home/dropbox
```

I've just done this, and although Dropbox initially seemed to be confused (it thought that the destination folder was still not on a supported partition), after unlinking and relinking my account it is now syncing happily.