# 2FA with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, two-factor-authentication

I'm using 2FA on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with Google Authenticator. I added `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok` to `/etc/pam.d/common-session` and correctly set up Google Authenticator.

The 2FA works great when getting back to a session after sleep mode. However when I shut my computer down and boot again, the 2FA doesn't prompt and I'm only asked to enter my master password. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 1.  Ubuntu desktop & server releases use the *year.month* format, only specialist releases use *year* format, such as Ubuntu Core 18 for use on IoT appliances.  What release do you mean? and why tag 18.04 & 18.10?

Comment: thanks for your comment, 18.10 was part of the suggestion. I'm working with Ubuntu desktop 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: I wonder if this write up on [PAM](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/3.26/gdm.html#PAM) in the GDM can be helpful to you. The GDM set up Ubuntu 18.04 Login appearance and procedures.

Comment: thanks @SunBear it was a good suggestion to help me identify which file to modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related to the encryption of home directory. As stated in Google Authenticator libpam

> If your system encrypts home directories until after your users
>   entered their password, you either have to re-arrange the entries in
>   the PAM configuration file to decrypt the home directory prior to
>   asking for the OTP code, or you have to store the secret file in a
>   non-standard location

. If you're the only user of your laptop, below are the steps to follow to boot Ubuntu 18.04 with 2FA:

- create an unencrypted directory, let's call it `ga`:

```
sudo mkdir -m 700 /home/ga
sudo chown yourname:yourgroup /home/ga
```

- when you run and configure Google Authenticator (i.e., command `google-authenticator` in a terminal), it creates a configuration file at the root directory. Copy this file to your unencrypted directory:

```
sudo cp ~/.google_authenticator /home/ga/.
```

- finally add this line at the end of the file `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password`:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/home/ga/.google_authenticator
```

Boot your computer and you should be good to go.

**Sources**

https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam#encrypted-home-directories

[Google Authenticator for Desktop (lightdm or gdm plugin)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193248/google-authenticator-for-desktop-lightdm-or-gdm-plugin)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Google_Authenticator#Desktop_logins

[Possible to Create Unencrypted Folder Outside Ecryptfs Home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086732/possible-to-create-unencrypted-folder-outside-ecryptfs-home)